# Mneisa table memory does not match size in DCD file

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I need your help. I am finding a way to get the mnesia table memory size. My table has the `disc_copies` type, it keeps 1 million records, occupying 144777931 words of mem.

Found the suggestion in other post,

`MnesiaMemoryMB = (mnesia:table_info(my_table, memory) * erlang:system_info(wordsize)) / (1024*1024).`

That makes sense to me, so the total bytes is 144777931*8 = 1158223448 ~ 1104MB. But the `my_table.DCD` file in the Mnesia directory occupied  278MB.

They are very different so I don't really know what causes this. Any suggestions would be highly appriciated.